# How to find all images containing any text?

Tags: images, ocr

I got a lot of images, and I need to find, which of them contain any text in English (to delete them). Is it possible to do it automatically?

Comment: "To delete them", that could be massive task, the program need to recognize the texts, fill in the missing background color

Comment: "to delete them" - to delete images, not the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an open source OCR engine, say [Tessaract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/), in order to figure out is there an english text or not.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the general idea that I need to use OCR, the question is - how to do it? Can tesseract return yes/no for each image? Or do I need to put text into file, and then analyze the created files?

Comment: Image -> OCR -> text file.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, sharing my solution:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.jpg" -or -name "*.png" \) -exec sh -c 'for x; do printf "%s :" "$x"; tesseract $x temp; if (grep -f blacklist temp.txt) then rm $x; rm temp.txt; fi; done' _ {} +
```

scans all subdirectories and deletes matching OCR patterns according to a file named "blacklist".
only problem: if there is a space in file, it doesn't parse it correctly and instead tries to run on the first word of the file.

edit: careful not to leave any blank lines on the blacklist file.